# ConnectionString In Class Library

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, class-library

I'm merging two of my projects that can share a lot of the same classes into one solution with two web applications and a shared class library.

I've literally just dumped all the classes into the class library project and as expected I've got a ton of errors to fix. My main problem at the moment is the connection string. Currently I have this (which is obviously not going to work):

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initialise the data access layer by loading the database connection string from the Web.Config file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Shared Sub New()

        _connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ClientFamilyManagementConnectionString").ConnectionString

    End
```

What do I do with my connection strings now the classes are not in a web application?

I really feel like I'm missing something here so below I'm include an example of a class from the BLL and DAL. I can't pass in the connection string to the constructor of the DAL - it says it can't have any parameters.

BLL:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace CompanyName

<Serializable()> Public Class SubMarketSector

    Private _id As Integer
    Private _name As String

    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetAllSubMarketSectors() As List(Of CompanyName.SubMarketSector)

        Dim newSubMarketSectorDAO As New SubMarketSectorDAO
        Return newSubMarketSectorDAO.GetAllSubMarketSectors

    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetSubMarketSectorByID(ByVal subMarketSectorID As Integer) As CompanyName.SubMarketSector

        Dim newSubMarketSectorDAO As New SubMarketSectorDAO
        Return newSubMarketSectorDAO.GetSubMarketSectorByID(subMarketSectorID)

    End Function


End Class

End Namespace
```

DAL:

```
Namespace CompanyName

Public Class SubMarketSectorDAO

    Private Const MainSelectByStatement As String = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Sub_Market_Sectors"
    Private Const MainOrderByStatement As String = " ORDER BY Name"

    Private Shared ReadOnly _connectionString As String = String.Empty

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initialise the data access layer by loading the database connection string from the Web.Config file
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Shared Sub New()

        _connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PursuitsConnectionString").ConnectionString

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a List of all Sub Market Sectors
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function GetAllSubMarketSectors() As List(Of CompanyName.SubMarketSector)

        '   Create the Connection
        Dim currentConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(_connectionString)

        '   Create the Command Object, set the CommandText, add any required Parameters and set the Connection
        Dim currentCommand As New SqlCommand
        currentCommand.CommandText = MainSelectByStatement & MainOrderByStatement
        currentCommand.Connection = currentConnection

        Dim listOfSubMarketSectors As New List(Of CompanyName.SubMarketSector)

        Using currentConnection

            '   Open the Connection
            currentConnection.Open()

            '   Create the DataReader and Execute the Command
            Dim currentDataReader As SqlDataReader = currentCommand.ExecuteReader()

            '   Populate the list with data
            Do While currentDataReader.Read

                Dim newSubMarketSector As CompanyName.SubMarketSector = PopulateSubMarketSector(currentDataReader)

                listOfSubMarketSectors.Add(newSubMarketSector)

            Loop

        End Using

        Return listOfSubMarketSectors

    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    '''  Return a single Sub Market Sector
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function GetSubMarketSectorByID(ByVal subMarketSectorID As Integer) As CompanyName.SubMarketSector

        '   Create the Connection
        Dim currentConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(_connectionString)

        '   Create the Command Object, set the CommandText, add any required Parameters and set the Connection
        Dim currentCommand As New SqlCommand
        currentCommand.CommandText = MainSelectByStatement & " WHERE ID = @subMarketSectorID" & MainOrderByStatement
        currentCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subMarketSectorID", subMarketSectorID)
        currentCommand.Connection = currentConnection

        Dim newSubMarketSector As New CompanyName.SubMarketSector

        Using currentConnection

            '   Open the Connection
            currentConnection.Open()

            '   Create the DataReader and Execute the Command
            Dim currentDataReader As SqlDataReader = currentCommand.ExecuteReader()

            '   Populate the Market Sector
            Do While currentDataReader.Read

                newSubMarketSector = PopulateSubMarketSector(currentDataReader)

            Loop

        End Using

        Return newSubMarketSector

    End Function

    Private Function PopulateSubMarketSector(ByVal currentDataReader As SqlDataReader) As CompanyName.SubMarketSector

        Dim newSubMarketSector As New CompanyName.SubMarketSector

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("ID"))) Then
            newSubMarketSector.ID = currentDataReader("ID")
        End If

        If Not (currentDataReader.IsDBNull(currentDataReader.GetOrdinal("Name"))) Then
            newSubMarketSector.Name = currentDataReader("Name")
        End If

        Return newSubMarketSector

    End Function

End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: You'll have to pass it to your data access layer when you instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the ConnectionStrings in each WebApplication and passing the specific connection string to the class library on instanciation. I don't know how you designed the class library (static methods, singleton, or whatever) but maybe you could pass them (each ConnectionString) to the constructor to set an instance variable which you later use (the same way like before).

Comment: Yeah I think I could do that pretty easily. Is that the standard/best practice way of handling connection strings given this example?

Comment: Having said that I can do it easily it doesn't seem quite right to me. Every single time I want to call a function or sub that performs data access I'll need to pass in the connection string. This doesn't conform with Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: @Westicle You only need to to do it once per instantiation. `Dim class As New YourClass(connectionsString)` So in `Sub New`, you can give your `_connectionString` property its value: `_connectionString = connectionString`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jack but the the constructor is in the class library so I'll still need to pass the connection string into that every time?

Comment: @Jack I have discovered that because of the way my classes are set up I can't do this at the moment. In my DAO the constructor is Shared and it won't let me pass in a parameter. I created my classes based on examples from a book. Do you think I need to re write my code?

Comment: @Westicle No, You could create a Public Property and set that before you use any functions in the class.

Comment: @Jack ok cool I can do that easily. It still feels odd to me that the page calling the function sets the connection string though. I'm going to have 2 projects using the same classes but I'll have to store the same connection string in 2 different places. I don't understand why the DAL shouldn't already know the connection string.

Comment: @Westicle The DAL doesn't know the connection string usually so it can be used on multiple projects as a .ddl. If you are just using it for this single project as a class you can just set it in the DAL itself.

Comment: @Jack ok I'm slowly starting to understand this after a rather heated debate with a colleague. I think I can see why you would pass the connection string to the library - cos the library is more of a set of rules than an actual.....thing/end..... in itself. (apologies, my mind/language is failing me at the mo).